# Data prepartion for a Neural Network (List as input and output). Recommendation is needed

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, normalization

Currently, I'm working on a DP project where I need to reorder lists, for example:

```
input_list = [1, 1, 2, 2]
output_list = [1, 2, 1, 2]
```

So, I have encoded my input and output lists with *to_categorical* function from Keras:

```
X = to_categorical(input_list, num_classes=10)
X
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

After I reshape them to 3D shape (for LSTM) :

```
X = X.reshape(1,4,10)
y = y.reshape(1,4,10)
```

For the loss function and metric I'm using ***binary_crossentropy*** and ***F1***.

My **issue** is accuracy. Sometimes I'm getting f.e. wrong numbers in the list:

y_out is `[1,2,2,2]` but I need `[1,2,1,2]`.

So, my **questions**:

- Is it a good idea to_categorical encoding data for my project?
- What about metric and loss function? Should I try something else?
- I'm really stack on this type of mistakes -> my y_out is `[1,2,2,2]` but I need `[1,2,1,2]`. **Any ideas how to overcome it?**
- Also, if you know similar project, please share you knowledge.

Any feedback is welcome :)

Some additional data on my project:

Code:

```
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense
    import numpy as np

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Bidirectional(GRU(32, return_sequences=True), input_shape=(None, 1)))
    model.add(Dense(30, activation='elu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer='normal', use_bias=True))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001), 
              metrics=[f1])
    model.fit(a, y, epochs=5000, batch_size=500, callbacks = callbacks)
```

my model summary

---

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
bidirectional_11 (Bidirectio (None, None, 64)          6528      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_18 (Dense)             (None, None, 30)          1950      
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_8 (Batch (None, None, 30)          120       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_19 (Dense)             (None, None, 1)           31        
=================================================================
Total params: 8,629
Trainable params: 8,569
Non-trainable params: 60
```

Comment: The answer totally depends on "what" is your data.

Comment: @DanielMöller lists, as I showed in the beginning. F.e. I have input list `[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]` and want to get in the output of my network something like `[ 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1]`.

Answer (score 1):

If your list to be reordered is a sequence of 4 elements, then you should be really using a shape of `(BatchSize, 4, ?)`, where `?` can be 10 if they're classes or even just the raw number if the number is an actual numbervalue/intensity.

Comment: actually, this is exactly what I'm doing. The questions is how to overcome that NN error: my y_out is `[1,2,2,2]` but I need `[1,2,1,2]`.

Comment: I've added my code

Comment: You're using `(4,10,1)` -- Batch size = 4 --- Your network sees no relation between the 4 elements. It should be `(1, 4, 10)`, or `(AnyNumberOfSequences, 4, 10)`.

Comment: heh, you are right, a bad example, in my network I'm using this shape for X `(12356, 90, 1)`, there 12356 is number of lists, 90 is a list after to_categorical encoding.

Comment: should I go to (12356, 9, 10)?

Comment: But what is the lenght of the lists? 9 elements in sequence? If so, yes, `(12356 lists, 9 elements per list, 10 numbers represent the value of one element)`